# how do I join two tables and then find the find the top 5 custmer_names based on sales_amount and grouped by custmer name

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, dense-rank

Basically I want the top 5 custmer_name with maximum sales_amount grouped by custmer_name

```
with results as (
SELECT custmer_name, sales_amount from sales.customers inner join sales.transactions
on sales.customers.customer_code = sales.transactions.customer_code 
)

select *, dense_rank() over(partition by custmer_name order by sales_amount desc) as ranking  from results
```

[customers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in7tL.png)

[transactions table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilNZw.png)

[Result after join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIpuj.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compute the dense rank *inside* the CTE or subquery, and the filter on it outside:

```sql
WITH results AS (
    SELECT c.custmer_name, t.sales_amount,
           DENSE_RAN() OVER (PARTITION BY c.custmer_name
                             ORDER BY t.sales_amount DESC) AS ranking
    FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN transactions t
        ON c.customer_code = t.customer_code 
)

SELECT *
FROM results
WHERE ranking <= 5;
```